# C# Remove Decimal in Currency Only If No Cents using String.Format

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I most efficiently remove decimals in a currency using String.Format **only** if the variable does not contain cents?

- So if Price is 200000, it should output: $200,000
- So if Price is 200000.00, it should output: $200,000
- If Price is 200000.10, it should output: $200,000.10
- If Price is 300.3, it should output: $300.30
- If Price is 20, it should output $20
- If Price is .2, it should output $0.20

etc...

I currently have:

```
$"{String.Format("{0:C}", Price)}"
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can do `Price % 1 == 0` to determine if it has cents or not and then use the appropriate format, either `C` for cents or `C0` for none.  Also for interpolated strings you don't need to use `string.Format` just do `$"{Price:C}"`, or since it's there isn't anything else in the string, just `Price.ToString("C")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do that by using a different format based on if the value mod 1 is equal to zero

```
Price.ToString(Price % 1 == 0 ? "C0" : "C");
```

Comment: This seems to work well and produce no issues - let me test some more.

Comment: Deleted my answer and adding proposed rendering code here: `@(Price % 1 == 0 ? $"{Price:c0}" : $"Price:c}");`

Comment: @MiaSno don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: @RoarS. I ended up using your format - with the expressions because I have other text around it. For my example I stripped a lot of my code for simplicity sake. Thank you for your input as well even though I will mark this answer as accepted answer I just want you to know I appreciate your contribution as well.